# CCMotionManager, accelerometerData, gyroData, magnetometerData return nil

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I'm working from Apple's [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1). I'm using the pull method described near `startAccelerometerUpdates`. The pull method is fine for my purposes since I only need to read from the sensor once.

I'm getting a nil from the calls to `accelerometerData`, `gyroData` and `magnetometerData` in the code below on an iPhone 4, iPad Mini, and iPad Retina. `isAccelerometerAvailable,`isGyroAvailable`, and`isMagnetometerAvailable`each return`YES`. Two questions:

How does one determine the result from `startAccelerometerUpdates` and `startGyroUpdates`? They are `void` functions, so can I assume it can never fail? (Otherwise, it would throw or return a `BOOL`).

How does one get the last error from the call to `accelerometerData`, `gyroData` and `magnetometerData`?

EDIT: I had to call `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.150f]` to get data out of the sensor. Anything less and the sensor does not produce valid data.

The sleep adds a third question: how long does one need to pause to ensure the data arrives when the hardware is present?

Thanks in advance.

```
static CryptoPP::RandomPool pool;
static dispatch_once_t once = 0;

dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock seed(32);
    CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(true, seed.data(), seed.size());
    pool.IncorporateEntropy(seed.data(), seed.size());
});

// First, send in all the uninitialized data. Then:
//  sesnors[0,1,2] use accelerometer, if available
//  sesnors[3,4,5] use gyroscope, if available
//  sesnors[6,7,8] use magnetometer, if available
CryptoPP::SecBlock<double> sensors(3 * 3);
pool.IncorporateEntropy(sensors.BytePtr(), sensors.SizeInBytes());

CMMotionManager* mgr = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if(mgr) {

    [mgr startAccelerometerUpdates];
    [mgr startGyroUpdates];
    [mgr startMagnetometerUpdates];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.150f];

    if([mgr isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
        CMAccelerometerData* accelData = [mgr accelerometerData];
        if(accelData) {
            sensors[0] = [accelData acceleration].x;
            sensors[1] = [accelData acceleration].y;
            sensors[2] = [accelData acceleration].z;
        }
    }

    if([mgr isGyroAvailable]) {
        CMGyroData* gyroData = [mgr gyroData];
        if(gyroData) {
            sensors[3] = [gyroData rotationRate].x;
            sensors[4] = [gyroData rotationRate].y;
            sensors[5] = [gyroData rotationRate].z;
        }
    }

    if([mgr isMagnetometerAvailable]) {
        CMMagnetometerData* magnetData = [mgr magnetometerData];
        if(magnetData) {
            sensors[6] = [magnetData magneticField].x;
            sensors[7] = [magnetData magneticField].y;
            sensors[8] = [magnetData magneticField].z;
        }
    }

    pool.IncorporateEntropy(sensors.BytePtr(), sensors.SizeInBytes());

    [mgr stopMagnetometerUpdates];
    [mgr stopGyroUpdates];
    [mgr stopAccelerometerUpdates];
    [mgr release], mgr = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
mgr startAccelerometerUpdates];
[mgr setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:0.01f];
```

That means you will not start receiving information until 0.01 seconds later, and even then you'll *only receive updates if the main thread is idle*.

You are not waiting 0.01 seconds before checking for data, you're actually waiting about 0.00000000001 seconds. And I'm not sure, but I think your main thread might need to be idle even if you do wait longer.

I think you should go back to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW4) and have a look how you're supposed to read information from the sensors.

I recommend using blocks to process the motion data:

```
[mManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
    // process data
}];
```

You could tell the accelerometer to stop immediately after receiving the first value, if you only want it once.

Comment: Thanks Abhi. I tried without `setAccelerometerUpdateInterval` and friends. How does one immediately start receiving info (with out those settings, I could not get anything out of the sensors). How does one fetch error information?

Comment: Thanks again Abhi. I don't believe this is correct: "you're actually waiting about 0.00000000001 seconds". According to the docs, "the interval units are in seconds".

Comment: Thanks again Abhi. Do you have a reference for this: " and even then you'll only receive updates if the main thread is idle"? The docs I am working from don't mention idle requirements. (My reference is in the first paragraph).

Comment: Thanks again Abhi. "I recommend using blocks to process the motion data". Well, I chose the pull method because I wanted a synchronous read within the `GetRandomPool` function. A push with its asynchronous callback block is pretty much out of the question. Plus, it really complicates a simple design and implementation.

Comment: @noloader I don't know if the main thread needs to be idle, haven't read that anywhere. But my experience working with iOS and OS X before that says it is probably true, even if it's not documented explicitly. Just because you're using "pull" doesn't mean the OS under you is doing pull. There is a good chance push is the only way it can be done, and pull is just a wrapper around push - which may well require the main thread to be idle. In general, the main thread in Obj-C should never be active for more than a few milliseconds at a time - anything more and it should be done on another thread.

Comment: When I say "you're waiting 0.0000000001 seconds" I mean you're telling it to start monitoring the hardware sensor and then immediately asking for data. You should be waiting several thousand CPU cycles before trying to pull the data, or else there won't be anything available yet.

Comment: Thanks again Abhi. I hope I did not come off argumentative. Just trying to figure out what needs to be done due to gaps in the documentation.

Comment: @noloader no problems. :-) most of apple's documentation assumes you have read all of the other documentation, which requires several years of reading. :-/